# how to calculate difference between two date in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to calculate the difference between two dates and have the duration in days in `duree` fields
My file.py is:

```
date_debut= fields.Date(string="Date debut")
date_fin= fields.Date(string="Date fin")
duree= fields.Date(string="Durée")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
    date_debut = fields.Date(string="Date debut")
    date_fin = fields.Date(string="Date fin")
    duree = fields.Char(string="Durée", compute="_duration", store=True)

    @api.depends('date_debut','date_fin')
    def _duration(self):
        if self.date_debut and self.date_fin:
            for rec in self:
                init_date = dt.strptime(rec.date_debut, '%Y-%m-%d')
                end_date = dt.strptime(rec.date_fin, '%Y-%m-%d')
                rec.duree= str((end_date - init_date).days)
```

Comment: When i try, i got this error: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date

Comment: @HyacintheOUATTARA  updated, check it out. It's work for me.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! here is what I did and that works: date_debut= fields.Date(string="Date debut")
 date_fin= fields.Date(string="Date fin")
 duree= fields.Integer(string="Durée (Jours)", compute= "_duration") @api.depends('date_debut','date_fin')
 def _duration(self):
  if self.date_debut and self.date_fin:
   for rec in self:
    rec.duree= (rec.date_fin - rec.date_debut).days

Answer (score 0):

Please first of all import the following:

```
import datetime
from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT as DF
```

then the following code will calculate the difference for you between two dates:

```
date_debut= fields.Date(string="Date debut")
date_fin= fields.Date(string="Date fin")
duree= fields.Char(string="Durée", compute="compute_duration")

def display_hours_minutes(self, seconds, granularity=2):
    result = []

    for name, count in intervals:
        value = seconds // count
        if value:
            seconds -= value * count
            if value == 1:
                name = name.rstrip('s')
            result.append("{} {}".format(value, name))
    return ', '.join(result[:granularity])

def compute_duration(self)
    for r in self:
        date_debut = datetime.datetime.strptime(r.date_debut, DF + ' %H:%M:%S')
        date_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(r.date_fin, DF + ' %H:%M:%S')
        date_diff = date_fin - date_debut
        r.duree = r.display_hours_minutes(date_diff.seconds)
```

The output will be like this:

```
0 Days, 23 hours, 45 minutes
```